# Can someone explain this function and how to type it in Haskell (infix, :-:)

Tags: haskell, types, infix-notation

```
infixr 5 :-:  
data List a = Empty | a :-: (List a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)
```

we just wrote a :-: (List a) instead of Cons a (List a). Now, we can write out lists in our list type like so:

```
ghci> 3 :-: 4 :-: 5 :-: Empty  
(:-:) 3 ((:-:) 4 ((:-:) 5 Empty))  
ghci> let a = 3 :-: 4 :-: 5 :-: Empty  
ghci> 100 :-: a  
(:-:) 100 ((:-:) 3 ((:-:) 4 ((:-:) 5 Empty)))
```

I get that :-: is supposed to work like Cons but I don't really get why we are allowed to do that and how to actually type infixr 5 :-: .

Comment: You surround the lines with `:{` and `:}` in the terminal to pass a multiline statement.

Comment: It worked thank you so much now I only need to know why I can write :-: instead of Cons and why simply writing : isn't allowed

Comment: Or you can write it in one line if you separate the declarations with a semi-colon.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "simply writing : isn't allowed". You *can* use that to build a list: `1:2:3:[] == [1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get that `:-:` is supposed to work like `Cons` but I don't really get why we are allowed to do that …

Because the [Haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-690004.2.1) says so.  In the grammar the *constr* is a data constructor. The *constr* can be a *con* followed by zero, one or more types, a *con* followed by record syntax, or a type, an operator *conop* followed by another type. This is [defined as](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-18000010.5):

> ```
> constr  →  con [!] atype1 … [!] atypek
>         |  (btype | ! atype) conop (btype | ! atype)
>         |  con { fielddecl1 , … , fielddecln }
> ```

The *conop* can be an operator *consym*, or an infix variant of an identifier between backticks, like `` `foo` ``, which is written in the [grammar section](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-18000010.5) as:

> ```
> conop    →  consym | ` conid `
> ```

The [grammar](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-17700010.2) specifies that a *consym* is defined as:

> ```
> consym → ( : {symbol })〈reservedop〉
> ```

so a colon followed by a sequence of symbols and such symbol should not be a reserved operator like `:`, `::`, etc.

This thus means that except for the reserved operators, you can use operators that start with a colon (`:`) as a data constructor.

> … and how to actually type `infixr 5 :-:`.

You can write multiline statements by surrounding these with `:{` and `:}`:

```
ghci> :{
| infixr 5 :-:  
| data List a = Empty | a :-: (List a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)
| :}
```